# Calculating the Power of the Upper Sideband

Tags: analog, communication, amplitude-modulation

I solved a question in a book that goes like this:

If the carrier power is 1000 watts, what is the power in the USB at 70.7% modulation?

I solved it using the formula:

$$ P_{USB}=\frac{m^{2} P_{C}}{4} $$

and I get the answer $$ P_{USB} = 176.75 \textrm{Watts} $$

but the answer provided by the book says it is $$ P_{USB} = 125 \textrm{Watts} $$

I want to ask who got it right, me or the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ P_{USB}=\frac{m^{2} P_{C}}{4} $$

Therefore

$$ P_{USB}=\frac{0.7071^{2} \times 1000}{4} $$

Which equals 125 watts

Perhaps you forgot to square the 0.7071?